# How can I load a DSO with no versioning information?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, ld, musl

How can I make the dynamic loader load a library with no versioning information for a library/executable that requires versioning information?

For example, say I am trying to run `/bin/bash` which requires symbol S with version X.Y.Z and `libtinfo.so.6` provides symbol S but due to being built with a musl toolchain has no versioning information. Currently, this gives me the following error:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 112: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

I am trying to avoid the process [described here](http://blog.fesnel.com/blog/2009/08/25/preloading-with-multiple-symbol-versions/) where I make a custom DSO that essentially maps all symbols (i.e. I would have to write out each symbol) to the appropriate symbol in the musl library. I have seen a lot of discussion about loading older versions of symbols in a DSO, but nothing about NO symbol versions.

Does this require me to recompile all binaries with versioned symbol so they don't include versioning information?

Thanks for your help!

## Update

After some investigation, I found that `/bin/bash` has a handful of symbols that it gets from `libtinfo.so.6` such as `tgoto`, `tgetstr`, `tputs`, `tgetent`, `tgetflag`, `tgetnum`, `UP`, `BC,` and `PC`. When the dynamic loader tries to find the correct version of these symbols (for example, `tputs@NCURSES6_TINFO_5.0.19991023`) in the musl-built `libtinfo.so.6` it fails as there is no versioning information in that file.

I think I have the beginnings of a hack-y solution (hopefully there is a better one out there). Essentially, I make a DSO that I compile with a GNU toolchain and load with `LD_PRELOAD`. In this DSO, I open the musl-built `libtinfo.so.6.1` with `dlopen` and use `dlsym` to get the needed symbols. These symbols are then made globally available. While there is no version information for `libtinfo.so.6`, there are version sections (`.gnu.version` and `.gnu.version_r`), and I am able to execute bash without any errors/warning. The DSO source is below:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

/* Functions */
static char *(*tgoto_internal)(const char *string, int x, int y);
static char *(*tgetstr_internal)(const char * id, char **area);
static int (*tputs_internal)(const char *string, int affcnt, int (*outc)(int));
static int (*tgetent_internal)(char *bufp, const char *name);
static int (*tgetflag_internal)(const char *id);
static int (*tgetnum_internal)(const char *id);

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) init(void);

/* Library Constructor */
void
init(void)
{
    void *handle = dlopen("/usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libtinfo.so.6.1", RTLD_LAZY);

    tgoto_internal = dlsym(handle, "tgoto");
    tgetstr_internal = dlsym(handle, "tgetstr");
    tputs_internal = dlsym(handle, "tputs");
    tgetent_internal = dlsym(handle, "tgetent");
    tgetflag_internal = dlsym(handle, "tgetflag");
    tgetnum_internal = dlsym(handle, "tgetnum");
}

char *
tgoto(const char *string, int x, int y)
{
    return tgoto_internal(string, x, y);
}

char *
tgetstr(const char * id, char **area)
{
    return tgetstr_internal(id, area);
}

int 
tputs(const char *string, int affcnt, int (*outc)(int))
{
    return tputs_internal(string, affcnt, outc);
}

int 
tgetent(char *bufp, const char *name)
{
    return tgetent_internal(bufp, name);
}

int
tgetflag(const char *id)
{
    return tgetflag_internal(id);
}

int
tgetnum(const char *id)
{
    return tgetnum_internal(id);
}

/* Objects */
char * UP = 0;
char * BC = 0;
char PC = 0;
```

However this solution doesn't seem to work all the time, and I still see the same warning as above when testing musl-built binaries, but this time, they don't crash the tests and just print a warning.

---

It should also be noted that I encountered a similar versioning error before with `libreadline.so` looking for versioning information in `libtinfo.so`. This seemed to have stemmed from my musl-built `libreadline.so` being the wrong version (8 instead of 7) and thus my configuration script went to the GNU `libreadline.so` which was version 7 and this tried to pull in the musl `libtinfo.so` which raised the error. Building `libreadline.so.7` with the musl toolchain resolved this error perfectly.

Comment: Basically, you should make sure that locally compiled libraries and programs don't interact with the default libraries and program. For example your own locally compiled components go under `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`, but _don't_ add the latter into `/etc/ld.so.conf`, instead use linker-options `-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib` when compiling from source.

Comment: Hi @LorinczyZsigmond thanks for the response. All of my locally compiled components are under `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/bin` and they aren't added to `ld.so.conf`. When I configure and make (using autoconf) I pass environment variables such as `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I think my use of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` might be a bit of an issue as it tells GNU binaries (like bash) to link against musl libraries.

Comment: Well, it's the shared objects (or shared libraries) what matter: locally compiled shared objects should be searched first by locally compiled programs, but be hidden from the 'default' programs. This can be solved with the mentioned gcc-option. (Earlier `-R dir` option was used for this, now it has become simply `-Wl,-rpath,dir`) See also command `readelf -d yourbinary | grep RUNPATH` -- it will show the result of this option.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond this fixed my issue - thank you so much for your help! If you want to type up an answer/explanation I can give you the bounty + close this question.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it is okay as it is. Best wishes.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I answered the question to close it. Let me know if you have anything else to add :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @LorinczyZsigmond for helping me arrive at the solution! Since they don't want to post a complete answer, I will to close the question.

The error:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 112: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

tells us that `/bin/bash` is looking for `libtinfo.so.6` in the musl `lib` directory. However, if we look at `/bin/bash` under `ldd` we see that in general it looks for DSO's in GNU's `lib` directory:

```
$ ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd485f7000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f58ad8ba000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f58ad8b5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f58ad6f4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => //lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f58ada22000)
```

When `/bin/bash` is run and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable points to the musl `lib` directory, the loader will try to resolve the `libtinfo.so.6` dependency with musl's `libtinfo.so.6`, not GNU's. This causes a conflict since `/bin/bash` was linked against GNU's `libtinfo.so.6` which has symbol versioning and perhaps more.

The fix, as said by @LorincyZsigmond, is:

> locally compiled shared objects should be searched first by locally compiled programs, but be hidden from the 'default' programs.

So essentially I needed to not mix the GNU and musl libraries which I was doing by heavy-handedly setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/lib`.

Instead of using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I used the `rpath` linker option (`-L/usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl/lib`) to hard-code the path to my musl libraries into the executable. This allows musl-built binaries to link against the DSO's the need while also allowing for GNU-built binaries to link against GNU-built DSOs (both of which are required when doing something like testing vim built from source).

As an aside: The `rpath` entries in an ELF's dynamic section are searched first.